# Simple coin toss in python tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, random

I am trying simple toss a coin program in python and I get an error which I don't know how to handle.
I also tried to search search for the error but I didn't get it from internet.

my code:-

```
import numpy.random as r
from tkinter import *

def toss():
    random_no = r.randint(0,2)
    #print(random_no)
    if random_no == 1:
        l1=Label(root,Text="Heads",font=("Arial", 10))
        #l1.place(x=100,y=100)
        l1.pack()
    else:
        l2=Label(root,Text="Tails",font=("Arial", 10))
        #l2.place(x=100,y=100)
        l2.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
b1 = Button(root, text="Toss the Coin", font=("Arial", 10), command=toss)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Errors:-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_8.py", line 12, in toss
    l2=Label(root,Text="Tails",font=("Arial", 10))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mispelled `text` option as `Text`
Try this:

```
import numpy.random as r
from tkinter import *

def toss():
    random_no = r.randint(0,2)
    #print(random_no)
    if random_no == 1:
        l1=Label(root,text="Heads",font=("Arial", 10))
        #l1.place(x=100,y=100)
        l1.pack()
    else:
        l2=Label(root,text="Tails",font=("Arial", 10))
        #l2.place(x=100,y=100)
        l2.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
b1 = Button(root, text="Toss the Coin", font=("Arial", 10), command=toss)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to pass a `Text` parameter to a `Label`, but python accounts for case, so it should be `text`. Use `Label(root, text="...` instead. Hope that's helpful!